# Forgerock error "An error occurred while processing this request. Contact your administrator"

Tags: openam, forgerock

I am using Access Management(OPENAM) version 6.5.1 and I download this Access Management
Eval6.5.1 war file using this site 
https://backstage.forgerock.com/downloads/browse/am/latest.
After  configured
I go to  Realms > Realm Name > Dashboard > Configure OAuth Provider > Configure OpenID Connect page.But I have an error.[image]
How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you running AM on JDK11?

Comment: @PeterMajor yes .jdk-11 and apache-tomcat-9.0.20

Comment: Have a read of: https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/6.5/release-notes/#java11-limitations and https://backstage.forgerock.com/knowledge/kb/article/a53786484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running AM on JDK 11, the old console pages will not work. This is a known limitation of version 6.5.x, and it's documented in the [release notes](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/6.5/release-notes/#java11-limitations). There is also a [knowledge base article](https://backstage.forgerock.com/knowledge/kb/article/a53786484) that tries to give some guidance on how to work this around for now.